# Como usar um comando python no Windows?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, windows

Fiz um código Python que pega uma planilha excel com dados do Brasil todo e cria vários arquivos separados por estados.
Ex: planilha mãe contém dados de SP, RJ, BH, RS e etc...

O python pega essa planilha mãe e separa todos os estados, criando um arquivo separado para cada estado com sua respectiva sigla.
Ex: Planilha RJ, Planilha SP, Planilha BH e etc.

Até aí blz. Só que isso está no colab. Como é algo da empresa, queria fazer isso dentro do PC da empresa e instalei o python e IDLE mas não sei como fazer rodar esse código dentro da IDLE.

No colab a gente importa o pandas entre outras bibliotecas. Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer isso usando o PC da empresa que contém o python e IDLE?

Obs: não coloquei o código porque o código me atende. Meu problema está em colocar isso pra rodar no python e IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Só pra entender..

Vi que você fez no colab gostaria de saber se seu código python seria um notebook, o arquivo é do tipo **ipynb**?

Caso for um arquivo notebook, será necessário que você tenha um ambiente pra atender isso. Normalmente é usado o **Jupyter**, você pode baixa-lo de forma **independente**, configurar ele por **vscode** ou baixar a ferramenta de ciências de dados **Anaconda**, onde ira conter a ferramenta.

O Jupyter fara o mesmo papel do colab só que localmente na sua maquina, lembrando que você terá que fazer seu próprio ***workspace***,.

A diferença é que no colaboratory, você esta projetando tudo por um servidor em nuvem da própria Google.

-Nesse ambiente você vai trabalhar igual no colab, importara seus arquivos csv, importara as bibliotecas pandas que foi utilizado no seu projeto e executara conforme sua organização em código.

Segue aqui os links:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Instalação:** https://jupyter.org/install

**Documentação:** https://jupyter.org/documentation

**Opcional baixar via Anaconda:**  https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

**Exemplo do Projeto Jupyter:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se for apenas um codigo python simples. Faça o download do mesmo

Com o python instalado na maquina, ele vem  acompanhado de modo nativo um terminal para execuções.

É bem simples, va no seu arquivo .py.

- Clique com Botão direito > Abrir com > Selecionar cmd do Python.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-Após isso abrira um console com executando seu script.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi. Sendo assim já baixei e instalei o pycharm e o anaconda. Já estou com o arquivo .py que usei no colab. Ainda não mexi nele usando as ferramentas que baixei. Como estou engatinhando, ainda bate um pouco de medo. Estou procurando algum tutorial pra ver acontecer e ir fazendo aos poucos. Hoje essa planilha mãe fica na rede e tenho que descobrir como faço pra rodar esse código sempre que precisar atualizar as informações. Tipo criar um botão com macro vba ou alguma função que abra o arquivo, atualize e feche. Se souber como fazer e puder me orientar, serei grato.